# How to check if list contains consecutive numbers Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have below list:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12]
```

By looking at the above list, we can say it's not consecutive. In order to find that using python, we can use below line of code:

```
print(sorted(l) == list(range(min(l), max(l)+1)))
# Output: False
```

This gives output False because `5, 6, 7, 8, 9` are missing. I want to further extend this functionality to check how many integers are missing. Also to note, no duplicates are allowed in the list. For ex:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 14]
```

output of above list should be `[5, 1]` because `5` integers are missing between `4` and `10` and `1` is missing between `12` and `14`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see if the list contains consecutive numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575235/how-to-see-if-the-list-contains-consecutive-numbers)

Comment: `count_of_missing = max(l) - min(l) + 1 - len(l)` This assumes that your list `l` has no repeated elements and they are all integers.

Comment: just sort the list, then just check if adjacent element are consecutive or not. and based on this make your result, or just use hash map/dicionary, and check for every key (n-1) is there any another key which is it's adjacent number or not

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I tried this there is one problem (may be its just my use case), lets say list is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 14]` so `count_of_missing` is 6 because `5` integers are missing between `4` and `10` and `1` is missing between `12` and `14`. Is it not possible to get two different counts?

Comment: sorting the list is expensive. Iterate over the list and put the elements into a set keeping track of the min and max elements. Then if no numbers are missing, the difference between max and min should be equal to the number of elements in the set minus one

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki only if duplicates are not allowed

Comment: duplicates will be removed when creating the set. so the list [1,1,2,3,4] will be converted to (1,2,3,4) with 4 elements. the max-min will be 4-1=3  ->  3=4-1

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki duplicates are not allowed

Comment: then add a check: length of the list and the length of the set must be the same. However if duplicates are not allowed that's a vital piece of information to include in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answers the question from the comments of how to find out how many are missing at multiple points in the list.  Here we assume the list `arr` is sorted and has no duplicates:

```
it1, it2 = iter(arr), iter(arr)
next(it2, None) # advance past the first element
counts_of_missing = [j - i - 1 for i, j in zip(it1, it2) if j - i > 1]
total_missing = sum(counts_of_missing)
```

The iterators allow us to avoid making an extra copy of `arr`.  If we can be wasteful of memory, omit the first two lines and change `zip(it1, it2)` to `zip(arr, arr[1:])`:

```
counts_of_missing = [j - i - 1 for i, j in zip(arr, arr[1:]) if j - i > 1]
```

Comment: Thankyou. Just one question, your 2nd approach `zip(arr, arr[1:])` does it consume more memory than 1st approach and how?

Comment: @SAndrew: Yes. It makes one additional copy of `arr` when doing the slice `arr[1:]`.  It's a small price.  The same price you make when doing `sorted(arr)` rather than sorting in-place with `arr.sort()`.

Comment: If you assume that `arr` is sorted and contains no duplicates, then no need for a loop at all. You can write directly `total_missing = arr[-1] - arr[0] + 1 - len(arr)`.

Comment: @Stef: You miss where the OP commented "I tried this there is one problem (may be its just my use case), lets say list is [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 14] so count_of_missing is 6 because 5 integers are missing between 4 and 10 and 1 is missing between 12 and 14. Is it not possible to get two different counts?" My initial proposal was "`count_of_missing = max(l) - min(l) + 1 - len(l)` This assumes that your list l has no repeated elements and they are all integers." That had assumed an unsorted array because the initial question included `sorted(l)`.  I decided to dispense with that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 14]
C = []
D = True
for _ in range(1,len(L)):
    if L[_]-1!=L[_-1]:
        C.append(L[_]-L[_-1]-1)
        D = False
print(D)
print(C)
```

Here I have checked that a number at `ith index minus 1` is equal to its previous index. if not then D = false and add it to list

Answer (score 0):

here is my attempt:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 14]

not_in = [i not in l for i in range(min(l),max(l)+1)]
missed = [sum(g) for i,g in groupby(not_in) if i]

>>> missed
'''
[5, 1]
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily convoluted and potentially inefficient - if the `i`th element is `10` and the `i+1`th element is `20`, you know there are 9 numbers missing in between without having to count all the missing numbers

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, right, but what if the list is not sorted?

Comment: Then sorting it first [O(n log n)] is still more efficient than checking all possible integers in the range for membership in the list [>= O(n^2)]